# How can i remove the negatives in an indexed bracket, when there is at least one negative and at least one positive inside of a bracket?

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

```
sumranges= [4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
amounts=['+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '-2.5', '+5.0', '-5.0', '+5.0', '+5.0', '+25.0']

for i in range(0, len(amounts)):
    amounts[i] = float(amounts[i])
    
newarray=[]
count=0

if sum(sumranges) == len(amounts):    
    for sumrange in sumranges:
        start=int(sum(sumranges[0:count]))
        end=int(start+sumrange)
        newarray.append(sum( amounts[start:end] ) )
        count+=1
        
    print(newarray)
else:
    print("Sum of sumranges isn't equal to length of amounts array")
```

result is

```
[10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 10.0, 0.0, 0.0, 5.0, 5.0, 25.0]
```

However, result should be:

```
["+10.0", "+10.0", "+10.0", "+10.0", "+2.5", "+5.0", "+5.0", "+5.0", "+25.0"]
```

The first 0.0 happened because sum of +2.5 -2.5 is 0. Similar thing to the second 0.0 but this time with +5 -5. How can i remove the -2.5 so it's +2.5, and for the second one result should be +5. I can't just remove all the negatives because the code should also work for this second data:

```
sumranges=[4,2,2,1,1,1,1]
amounts=['-2.5', '-2.5', '-2.5', '-2.5', '-2.5', '-2.5', '-5.0', '-5.0', '-5.0', '-5.0', '-25.0', '+99.999999999']
```

result should be:

```
["-10.0", "-5.0", "-10.0", "-5.0", "-5.0", "-25.0", "+99.999999999"]
```

Comment: Can you explain the logic of the operation?

Comment: The code works like summing the first 4 in the second list, and then the next 4,  4, 4, and next 2. So it's the first list is used as range for the second list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IIUC, you could filter out your negative numbers:

```
sumranges= [4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
amounts=['+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '-2.5', '+5.0', '-5.0', '+5.0', '+5.0', '+25.0']

out = []
start=0
for step in sumranges:
    end = start+step
    l = list(map(float, amounts[start:end]))
    if len(set(i < 0 for i in l)) > 1:
        l = [i for i in l if i>0]
    s = sum(l)
    out.append('%s%.1f' % ('+' if s >=0 else '' , s))
    start = end
    
out
```

output:

```
['+10.0', '+10.0', '+10.0', '+10.0', '+2.5', '+5.0', '+5.0', '+5.0', '+25.0']
```

output with second input:

```
['-10.0', '-5.0', '-10.0', '-5.0', '-5.0', '-25.0', '+100.0']
```

Comment: the code should also work for the second data, like mentioned in the post. sumranges=[4,2,2,1,1,1,1]
amounts=['-2.5', '-2.5', '-2.5', '-2.5', '-2.5', '-2.5', '-5.0', '-5.0', '-5.0', '-5.0', '-25.0', '+99.999999999']. With result: ["-10.0", "-5.0", "-10.0", "-5.0", "-5.0", "-25.0", "+99.999999999"]. That's why i can't just remove all the negatives.

Comment: Well you logic is unclear. How do you decide what -x+y is?

Comment: you decide it because of the range, for example, if sumranges, the 4th item, which is 2. This means in the amounts list, it is 2 numbers, those are '+2.5', '-2.5'. Because 4 + 4 + 4 + 4, and now you hit 2, which means the 15th and 16th number in the amounts list, which is '+2.5', '-2.5', so i need to remove -2.5 (the negative in this).

Comment: Sorry, this is not a clear explanation, check my update anyway.

Comment: I want to take a list and then selectively sum a range from that list? Then sum the net range from the last index of the previous range summed, etc.

Answer (score 0):

There's a question with this answer. This code will give the desired result for your second example (except for the formatting of the 99.99999) value.

If I apply the same data as per your first example, it gives the output that you say is wrong.

Your explanations about why and when you want to "remove" a negative value is unclear.

So, by showing you this code it might help you to clarify what you need:-

```
def process(s, a):
    assert sum(s) == len(a)
    n = []
    o = 0
    for _s in s:
        t = sum(list(map(float, a[o:o+_s])))
        n.append(f'{t:+.2f}')
        o += _s
    return n

sumranges = [4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
amounts = ['+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5',
           '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '-2.5', '+5.0', '-5.0', '+5.0', '+5.0', '+25.0']

print(process(sumranges, amounts))

sumranges = [4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1]
amounts = ['-2.5', '-2.5', '-2.5', '-2.5', '-2.5', '-2.5',
           '-5.0', '-5.0', '-5.0', '-5.0', '-25.0', '+99.999999999']

print(process(sumranges, amounts))
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use an iterator to form the range groups inside a list comprehension, then subtract the sum of negatives from the group's sum if the largest element is not a negative.

Here is a function that will do it (on a list of proper numeric values):

```
def sumPosRanges(amounts,sumranges):
    return [ sum(r)-sum(n for n in r if n<0)*(max(r)>0)
             for iAmounts in [iter(amounts)] for sr in sumranges
             for r in [[next(iAmounts) for _ in range(sr)]] ]
```

First input:

```
sumranges= [4, 4, 4, 4, 2, 2, 1, 1, 1]
amounts=['+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5',
         '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5', '+2.5',
         '+2.5', '-2.5', '+5.0', '-5.0', '+5.0', '+5.0', '+25.0']

sums = sumPosRanges(map(float,amounts),sumranges)
           
print([f"{s:+3.1f}" for s in sums])        
['+10.0', '+10.0', '+10.0', '+10.0', '+2.5', '+5.0', '+5.0', '+5.0', '+25.0']
```

Second input:

```
sumranges=[4,2,2,1,1,1,1]
amounts=['-2.5', '-2.5', '-2.5', '-2.5', '-2.5', '-2.5', 
         '-5.0', '-5.0', '-5.0', '-5.0', '-25.0', '+99.999999999']

sums = sumPosRanges(map(float,amounts),sumranges)
           
print([f"{s:+3.1f}" for s in sums])        
['-10.0', '-5.0', '-10.0', '-5.0', '-5.0', '-25.0', '+100.0']
```